# delete duplication in a table and retain one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The main table is `Table2` and I want to delete duplication `RollID` in `Table1` but retaining 1 like the example below `6456` (Note: Primary Keys Table ID's are auto-incremental)

Table 1 (child table)

```
Table1_ID   RollID
 1          6456 
 2          6456 
 3          6459
```

Table2 (Parent)

```
Table2_ID    RollID
 1            6456 
 2            6459
```

How can I attain this scenario.. Your helping hand is highly appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT Table1_ID, RollID,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY RollID ORDER BY RollID)
   FROM dbo.Table1
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

Comment: Is this legal in MS SQL?

Comment: I am receiving an error in Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: @Jake:- was missing a comma. Fixed that. Apologies!

Comment: I am receiving an error View or function 'CTE' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables.

Comment: @Jake:- Is it that you are trying to insert the record into your parent table which does not have duplicated records?

Comment: I already solved the problem.. enabled cascading...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM Table1 GROUP BY ROLLID)
```